# Mysql listing the records from the table in php in monthly wise?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table like

```
id   title            date           filename
-----------------------------------------------
1    Sample Title    2014-10-08      file.pdf

2    Sample Title1   2014-07-09      file1.pdf

3    Title 3         2014-07-04      file2.pdf
```

In this list i have to order by date in desc order so that i can able to fetch last record in the first position. for this i used

```
select * from table_name ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( date ) , '%Y-%m-%d' ) DESC
```

My pblm is i have  to arrange them monthly wise with the month as the title like

July 2014 -----> {title}
under this title the records in the table of july month 2014 should be listed and so on in PHP.
Kindly help to solve the issue. Thank You

Comment: It leaves open what you have tried so far

Comment: `concat(date)`? what's the point of concatenating a single variable? And if that's a crazy version of casting a `date` to a string, then it's definitely useless. ``ORDER BY `date` `` would be FAR more efficient.

Comment: as i am newbie i can't understand concat etc i just took it off from google kindly try to help to solve the issue

Comment: have you tried :ORDER BY MONTH(date) DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
<?php
define("01","January");
define("02","Feb");
define("03","March");
define("04","April");
define("05","May");
define("06","June");
define("07","July");
define("08","Aug");
define("09","Sept");
define("10","Oct");
define("11","Nov");
define("12","Dec");

$con = mysql_connect("hostname","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('trial', $con) or die( mysql_error());
$sql="select * from experiment group by date desc";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr><th>title</th>"."<th>date</th>"."<th>filename</th></tr>";

$last_value=null;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{     
        $date=$row['date'];
        $date_exploded = explode("-",$date);
        $value = $date_exploded[1];
        if($value == $last_value){
          echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td><td>" .constant($value).</td><td>".$row['filename']."</td></tr>";
        }
        else{
          $last_value=$value;
          echo "<tr><td><div>separator</div></td><td>separator</div></td><td><div>separator</div></td></tr>";
          echo "<tr><td>".$row['title']."</td><td>" .constant($last_value)."</td><td>".$row['filename']."</td></tr>";
        }
}
        echo "</table>";
?>
```

Feel free to alter the separator div according to your styling format. 
The database I used is named 'trial' and the table I used is named 'experiment'

The experiment table schema is:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title    | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date     | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| filename | varchar(25) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = <<<__EOQUERY__
  select concat(date_format(`date`, '%b'), ' ', year(`date`)) as `month`, `title`
    from `books`
   order by `date` desc
__EOQUERY__;

$connection = new MySQLi('localhost','root','calistoga','test');

$result = $connection->query($query);

echo "<table>";
$lastmonth = null;
foreach ($result as $row)
{   
    $month = $row['month'];
    $title = $row['title'];

    if ($month !== $lastmonth)
    {   
        echo "<tr><th>{$month}</th>";
        $lastmonth = $month;
    }   
    else
        echo "<tr><td></td>";

    echo "<td>{$title}</td></tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";
```

1. Use date_format() in MySQL to format a date:
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format
2. Order by the actual date value, not the string value (This assumes your "date" column is of the date type, or some other temporal value)

Table definition used here:

```
create table `books` (
  `id` integer not null auto_increment,
  `title` varchar(255) not null,
  `date`  date not null,
  `filename` varchar(255),
  primary key (`id`)
) engine=InnoDB;

insert into `books` (`title`,`date`,`filename`)
values
('sample title1', '2014-12-31', 'file1.pdf'),
('sample title2', '2014-11-30', 'file2.pdf'),
('sample title3', '2014-11-24', 'file3.pdf'),
('sample title4', '2014-10-20', 'file4.pdf');
```

Comment: Obviously use your own connection details.